# How to set number picker value when the min and max are the same?

Tags: android, numberpicker

I can't seem to figure out how for a value into the numberpicker.  It always shows 0 when the min and max are the same.  Is there any way to ovveride it?  Here is my code.

```
int min = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RestaurantElementsTable.KEY_MIN_QUANITY));
                int max = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RestaurantElementsTable.KEY_MAX_QUANITY));
                int defaultQuanity = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RestaurantElementsTable.KEY_DEFAULT_QUANITY));

                if ( max - min == 0){

                    ((NumberPicker) view).setValue(defaultQuanity);

                }else {

                    ((NumberPicker) view).setMaxValue(max);
                    ((NumberPicker) view).setMinValue(min);
                    ((NumberPicker) view).setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

                    ((NumberPicker) view).setValue(defaultQuanity);


                }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `maxValue` and `minValue` in `NumberPicker` is 0. So you need to set `maxValue` and `minValue` before using `setValue`.

For example:

```
if ( max == min) {
    ((NumberPicker) view).setMaxValue(defaultQuanity);
    ((NumberPicker) view).setMinValue(defaultQuanity);

    ((NumberPicker) view).setValue(defaultQuanity);
}
```